# Inserting file record into object and then into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self,custid,name,addr,city,state,zipcode):
        self.custid=custid
        self.name=name
        self.addr=addr
        self.city=city
        self.state=state
        self.zipcode=zipcode
        self.memberLevel=BasicMember()
        self.monthlySpending =0

    def changeLevel(self,level):
        if level == 'gold':
            self.memberLevel = GoldMember()        
        elif level == 'silver':
            self.memberLevel = SilverMember()
        else:
            self.memberLevel = BasicMember()
```

Above is my customer class. I am trying to read customer data from a file and map it to a customer class object. Afterwards I want to insert each object in the dictionary. Currently I'm having trouble as it gives me an error:

```
cc=Customer.Customer(*item)
TypeError: __init__() takes 7 positional arguments but 61 were given.
```

`Customer1` is the name of the module I am importing.

```
for line in open('customers.dat','r'):
    item=line.rstrip()
    cc=Customer1.Customer(*item)
    s2=item.split(',',1)[0]
    d[s2]=[cc]
```

Here is some sample data in my `Customer.dat` file:

```
310933237,Temmin Wexley,898 Sullustan Street,Geonosis,MA,02100
286659823,Mace Windu,741 Bantha Street,Jakku,MA,02330
234101312,Wuher,932 Besalisk Street,Coruscant,MA,02169
721728168,Yaddle,30 Amani Road,D'Qar,MA,01508
492621787,Yoda,860 Amani Road,Endor,NH,03801
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `Customer(*item)` you are passing in a string (e.g. "310933237,Temmin Wexley,898 Sullustan Street,Geonosis,MA,02100") and so it gets expanded to the argument list 3, 1, 0, 9, .... etc.

Change it to something like:

```
item=line.rstrip()
input = line.split(',')
cc = Customer(*input)
```

to get your arguments split out correctly.

Comment: for line in open('customers.dat','r'):
 item=line.rstrip(',')
 intput =line.split(',')
 cc=Customer.Customer(*intput)
 s2=item.split(',',1)[0]
 d[s2]=[cc]

 
     print(d)
   {'739118188': [<Customer.Customer object at 0x005FF8B0>],   '578148567': [<Customer.Customer object at 0x005FF9B0>] }

Comment: Well above line works... only one issue. The object is getting stored in dictionary and i can see the memory location but can i access from dictionary each objects attributes ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but (for example) does `d['739118188'].name` do what you want?

Comment: well the above code works and as a result at each position in dictionary i get this value stored:                                                                             {'739118188': [<Customer.Customer object at 0x005FF8B0>] }                          so now if i want to access and print a particular object which has a key and print that objects attributes like name etc . how to do it . thanks alot

Comment: it gives this error : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'  so how to extract attribute from within an object stored in dictionary. Thanks

Comment: You've store the customer object in the dictionary as a list, so you need to extract the item from the list:
`d['739118188'][0].name`

Better still, if you don't need it in a list, don't put it in a list in the first place and just store it in your original code:

`d[s2] = cc`